# Problem with adding content

Tags: nodes

I allow my administators to add panels, articles, blog posts, forum topics, etc but it only shows the default set that regular users get which is blog posts and forum topics. Ive checked and all the people are set to admin. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to go into People -> Permissions -> Roles.  Find the administrator role and click on 'Edit Permissions'.

Then, go down to the Node section, and check off the appropriate permissions for viewing, creating, editing, deleting, etc.. that particular content type.  The permissions actually look like this:

```
Article: Create new content [ ]
Article: Edit own content   [ ]
Article: Edit any content   [ ]
Article: Delete own content [ ]
Article: Delete any content [ ]
```

You'll of course want to check off probably all of those if the role is an administrator, as typically they'll have absolutely power over your application.  That is, if it's what you intend.  The power of Drupal is yours :)

Comment: Still does not work.

Comment: Try clearing cache?